# Blocking Alexa users

Tags: php, redirect, proxy, user-agent, alexa-internet

I know this issue has been chewed and went through inside out.
I read all the posts in stackoverflow regarding this issue and still maybe someone can shed some light on this.

I want to block Alexa downstream click (dont show where people are coming and going from my site).

I tried:

1. Adding a proxy in front of my site
2. Blocking all users with alexa toolbar (by user agent) and redirecting them to fake sites
3. robots.txt

Still Alexa gathers all details about my site in less then a week.

Anyway to stop alexa from collecting data???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The proxy will not help you. Instead of your real server, now the proxy represents your site, but the traffic and content is completely the same. Useless.
2. Blocking access based on the user agent really has to be done right. And if you say "block", you should really mean "block", like in "Status 410 or 500 Go Away here is no content" block. If you cannot afford letting people be blocked from your content, because you somehow need some customers, then blocking does not work either.
3. robots.txt might actually work, if it would be evaluated by the Alexa bot. But as far as I understand Alexa, there is no bot, but effectively a browser toolbar that spies into anything the user receives in his browser, and sends it back to Alexa. Won't work either.

What will work? Go offline with your site.

Actually, I wonder why you care.

Comment: what's inside a robots.txt is a gentle request to exclude, not a must do.